# makes a database connection in the constructor using Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, pg

I am trying to implement knex connection below into an equivalent DB class. I searched but did not find any example implementation.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'your_database_user',
    password: 'your_database_password',
    database: 'myapp_test'
  },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let knex = require("knex");

class Database {
   
   constructor(connection) {
      this.connection = connection;
   }


   connect(option = {}) {
     this.instance = knex(Object.assign(this.connection, option));
   }

}


let db = new Database({
    connection: {
       host: '127.0.0.1',
       user: 'your_database_user',
       password: 'your_database_password',
       database: 'myapp_test'
    }
});

db.connect({
  pool: { min: 0, max: 7 },
  client: 'pg'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but how do I can pass client and pool options

Comment: @ahmad , I changed my answer again